# Form validation and MultiValueDictKeyError

Tags: python, django, validation

Django framework. Html form. views.py script.

I have a form with multiple checkboxes, the user chooses a checkbox in correspondence with what files they would like to download in a zip file.  When all boxes are checked, a zip file is created and able to download however whenever a checkbox is unchecked I get the following error:

MultiValueDictKeyError at /qatools/debug/logs/
Key 'logs' not found in QueryDict:

My validation is as follows.  It is determines whether a checkbox has been checked and assigns either a 0 or 1 as it is in the format that it calls a shell script.

```
    logs = 0
    if request.POST.get & request.POST['logs'] == "on":
        logs = 1
```

Comment: Never mind, fixed it.. Should have been:
        
        logs = 0
        if 'logs' in request.POST and request.POST['logs'] == "on":
            logs = 1

Comment: A shorter way to do the if statement: `if request.POST.get('logs') == "on":` since `get` is a function that will default to None if the key doesn't exist. See [QueryDict docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a standard issue with HTML forms ... on the POST an unchecked checkbox will NOT EXIST in the POST values, not have a value of 'off' as expected.  So you need to check for existence:

```
logs = 0
if request.POST.get and 'logs' in request.POST and request.POST['logs'] == "on":
    logs = 1
```

Comment: Yeah, i figured it out! Wouldnt let me answer tho. Thanks for replying anyways!